# Read file while it is being written by spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am using spark structured streaming for my application. I have use case where i need to read file while it is being written.
I tried with spark structured streaming as below:

```
sch=StructType([StructField("ID",IntegerType(),True),StructField("COUNTRY",StringType(),True)])
df_str = spark.readStream.format("csv").schema(sch). option("header",True).option("delimiter",','). load("<Load Path>")
query = df_str.writeStream.format("parquet").outputMode("append").trigger(processingTime='10 seconds').option("path","<HDFS location>").option("checkpointLocation","<chckpoint_loc>").start()
```

But it is reading only file initially, after that file is not getting read incrementally. i am thinking workaround to write file in temp directory and create new file after some time and copy to directory from spark structured streaming job is reading but this is causing latency.

Is there any other way to handle this(I can not use kafka)?

Sorry if this question is not for Stackoverflow because i did not find any other place to ask this question.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately Spark doesn't support it. The unit of file stream source is "file". Spark assumes that the files it reads are "immutable", which means the files shouldn't be changed once they're placed in source path. This makes offset management pretty much simpler (doesn't need to track file offsets), where the number of files in source path would keep increasing. Reasonable limitation, but still a limitation.